# What does this kanji mean?

Tags: kanji

[image]

What does this kanji mean? Is there more than one meaning, more than one interpretation?

Comment: Are you finding 眷?

Comment: Is that someone's tattoo?

Answer (score 3):

The kanji is:

### 眷

「眷{かえり}みる」 means "***to look back on***", "***to reflect on***", etc.  The kanji can mean those on its own as well.

The on-reading is 「けん」.

Unless you are planning on teaching Japanese literature at a Japanese graduate school, you would not need to know this kanji.